# Comparing int to NULL in C - is this tutorial incorrect?

Tags: c

I'm looking at this tutorial http://www.learn-c.org/en/Binary_trees and in the insert function it compares an int to NULL. It seems to run fine on the tut site but it didn't work for me and my research tells me it should not work. My code is below.

1. Am I wrong here or is the tutorial wrong?
2. If the tutorial is wrong is there any way to dynamically set the value for the first node of the BST? I thought about checking if left and right were both null but that would just keep resetting the first node. Having a third pointer for the value of the node seems wasteful but maybe it's the only way?

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <malloc.h>
   struct bstNode {
       int val;
       struct bstNode *left;
       struct bstNode *right;
   };

   int insert(struct bstNode *head, int val);

   void printDFS(struct bstNode *head);

   int main() {
       struct bstNode *bstTree = malloc(sizeof(struct bstNode));
       insert(bstTree, 8);
       insert(bstTree, 5);
       insert(bstTree, 98);
       insert(bstTree, 2);
       insert(bstTree, 15);
       insert(bstTree, 65);
       insert(bstTree, 15);
       printDFS(bstTree);
   }

   int insert(struct bstNode *head, int val) {
       //This is the problem statement, it contains random data when I debug as it's uninitialized
       if (head->val == NULL) {
           head->val = val;
           return 0;
       }

       if (val < head->val) {
           if (head->left != NULL) {
               return insert(head->left, val);
           } else {
               head->left = malloc(sizeof(struct bstNode));
               head->left->val = val;
               return 0;
           }
       } else {
           if (head->right != NULL) {
               return insert(head->right, val);
           } else {
               head->right = malloc(sizeof(struct bstNode));
               head->right->val = val;
               return 0;
           }
       }
   }

   void printDFS(struct bstNode *head) {
       if (head->left != NULL) printDFS(head->left);
       printf("%d ", head->val);
       if (head->right != NULL) printDFS(head->right);
   }
   ```

Comment: You right stop follow this tuto. Campare a int with NULL has no cense.

Comment: NULL is generally just 0 as an integer.

Comment: Check the definition of the `NULL` macro. For a good implementation, it should be a `void *` and the compiler should warn. Even **iff** `NULL` is defined as the integer `0`, this is very bad practice. As @Stargateur wrote: instantly close this site and find a better one or read a _good_ C book. They are still the best way to learn C, there are just too many bad tutorials in the net.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: While allowed, in C,. it is commonly `(void *)0`, not just `0` for good reason (e.g. to emit warnings for the construct above). You confuse C with C++!

Comment: @RetiredNinja And even if it "works", whatever value `NULL` equates to will cause all kinds of problems if it's inserted into the tree.

Comment: I never said it was a good thing, but it is an explanation why the code might compile and work when used as a sentinel value.  http://ideone.com/XNMtzV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial is incorrect.  It makes two invalid assumptions.

1. It assumes that `NULL` is equivalent to 0.  While in most cases it is defined at `(void *)0`, it won't always necessarily be the case.  It's also using a pointer where an `int` is expected, so there's a dependency on the representation of a pointer.
2. It assumes the initial node has 0 in `val`.  When memory is allocated with `malloc`, the memory is not initialized (as you've found out).

This code also functions by assuming that 0 is not a valid value to be inserted into the list, since it uses 0 for a sentinel value to denote an empty list.

Working with the assumption that 0 is used as a sentinel, the code can be fixed as follows.

First, when creating the initial node, use `calloc` instead of `malloc`.  The `calloc` function will initialize all bytes to 0.  This will give you an initial member with `val` set to 0 and both `left` and `right` set to `NULL`.

Also, you should always check the return value of `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc` in case they fail.

```
int main() {
    struct bstNode *bstTree = calloc(1, sizeof(struct bstNode));
    if (bstTree == NULL) {
        perror("calloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Second, get rid of the integer/pointer comparison by replacing `NULL` with 0.

```
    if (head->val == 0) {
```

Doing those 2 things should get the code to work properly.

Taking a step back and looking at the bigger picture, there are some design issues here.

The `insert` function returns an `int`, but the return value is never used.  In fact, this function can only ever return 0.  Better to change the return type to `void`.

Having an empty tree contain a single node with a sentinel value restricts the values you can put in.  Better to have an empty tree by having the head node being a `NULL` pointer.  This can be addressed in the insertion function by passing in the address of the head pointer so it can be modified if the list is empty:

```
void insert(struct bstNode **head, int val) {
    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = malloc(sizeof(struct bstNode));
        if (*head == NULL) {
            perror("malloc failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        (*head)->val = val;
        (*head)->left = NULL;
        (*head)->right = NULL;
        return;
    }

    if (val < (*head)->val) {
    ...
```

Then you call it like this:

```
struct bstNode *bstTree = NULL;
insert(&bstTree, 8);
...
```

Comment: What do you do if malloc fail ? how the error is return ?

Comment: @Stargateur Added notes on checking the return value of `malloc` and family.

Comment: Thanks you for the in-depth answer and especially for malloc checking and the general code review

Answer (score -1):

```
if (head->val == NULL) {
    head->val = val;
    return 0;
}
```

I think the tuto want check if val is NULL because insert return a int. You should replace insert function by something like that:

```
struct bstNode *new_bstNode(int val, struct bstNode *left, struct bstNode *right)
{
    struct bstNode *elem = malloc(sizeof(*elem));
    if (elem == NULL)
        return NULL;
    elem->val = val;
    elem->left = left;
    elem->right = right;
    return elem;
}

struct bstNode *insert(struct bstNode *head, int val) {
    if (head == NULL)
        return new_bstNode(val, NULL, NULL);

    if (val < head->val) {
        if (head->left != NULL)
            return insert(head->left, val);
        else
            return head->left = new_bstNode(val, NULL, NULL);
    } else {
        if (head->right != NULL)
            return insert(head->right, val);
        else
            return head->right = new_bstNode(val, NULL, NULL);
    }
}
```

So your main need to be replace by

```
int main() {
    struct bstNode *bstTree = insert(bstTree, 8);
    insert(bstTree, 5);
    insert(bstTree, 98);
    insert(bstTree, 2);
    insert(bstTree, 15);
    insert(bstTree, 65);
    insert(bstTree, 15);
    printDFS(bstTree);
}
```